# Event listener malfunction on Prev/Next button

Tags: javascript, html

in my many exercises I was trying to create a lightbox gallery using only Vanilla Javascript. For now it is really simply created so keep that in mind. Anyway, the issue is that when I click on the previous button it works equally as the next button. I don't understand why. Can you please give me a hint or maybe advice some better logic? Thanks

```js
let lightbox = document.getElementById("lightbox");
let lightboxTitle=document.getElementById("lightTitle");
let closeBtn=document.getElementById("close");
let nextBtn=document.getElementById("next");
let prevBtn=document.getElementById("prev");
let mainPic=document.getElementById("mainPic");
let picList = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails");
let gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
let navbar = document.getElementById("navbar_main");
let footer = document.getElementById("main_footer")
let thumbnails = [
    {
        src: "img/10.jpg",
        title: "Schody 1",
        class: "thumbnails",
        position: 1

    },
    {
        src: "img/17.jpg",
        title: "Schody 2",
        class: "thumbnails",
        position: 2

    },
    {
        src: "img/19.jpg",
        title: "Schody 3",
        class: "thumbnails",
        position: 3

    },
    {
        src: "img/31.jpg",
        title: "Schody 4",
        class: "thumbnails",
        position: 4

    }
];
for (let i=0;i<thumbnails.length;i++){
        let picBox = document.createElement("div")
        let newPic = document.createElement("img");
        let newPicTitle = document.createElement("h6");
        picBox.className="picBox";
        newPic.src = thumbnails[i].src;
        newPic.className=thumbnails[i].class;
        newPicTitle.innerHTML = thumbnails[i].title;
        newPic.position = thumbnails[i].position;
        picBox.appendChild(newPic);
        picBox.appendChild(newPicTitle);
        gallery.appendChild(picBox);
        picList[i].addEventListener("click",(e) => {
            lightbox.style.display="flex";
            mainPic.src=e.target.src;
            mainPic.position=e.target.position;
            lightboxTitle.innerHTML=e.target.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
            navbar.style.display="none";
            footer.style.display="none";
    })
       
}


closeBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    lightbox.style.display="none";
    navbar.style.display="";
    footer.style.display="";
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let mainPosition = parseInt(mainPic.position);
    let i= mainPosition++;
    mainPic.src = thumbnails[i].src;
    mainPic.position = thumbnails[i].position;
    lightboxTitle.innerHTML = thumbnails[i].title;
    
});

prevBtn.addEventListener("click",()=>{
    let mainPosition = parseInt(mainPic.position);
    let i= mainPosition--;
    mainPic.src = thumbnails[i].src;
    mainPic.position = thumbnails[i].position;
    lightboxTitle.innerHTML = thumbnails[i].title;
});
```

For the complete project [Visit my repo](https://github.com/iDome89/Site)

Comment: Firstly, reduce your code to the **minimum** required to replicate the error. Secondly, `let i= mainPosition--;` decrements *mainPosition* after assigning the value (as does `let i= mainPosition++`).

Comment: You can use `let i = mainPosition + 1` and `let i = mainPosition - 1`.

Comment: And you'd want to deal with cases when `i` will be zero, like when the user clicks the back button from the first image

Comment: yes I am keeping that in mind, but even with let i = mainPosition + 1 and -1 it doesn't work. the next button works ok, the previous, works the same way as the next.

Comment: @RobG I reduce the code as you suggested, do you have a suggestion on how I could change the logic inside the event listeners?

Comment: Posting the minimum code means reducing it to the minimum required to show the issue, not just removing most of it, see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stand, someone has a lot of work to do just to get something resembling a useful prototype, and that may be very different to what you have built.